# .NET Non/Generic Lists are stored on stack or heap?

Tags: c#, list, generics

What I want to know is where are stored the following lists, on stack or on heap?

1. Nongeneric list of value type

   ```
   int[] strArray = { 1, 2, 3 };
   ```
2. Nongeneric list of ref type

   ```
   Person[] personArray = new Person[1];
   personArray[0] = new Person();
   ```
3. Generic list of value type

   ```
   List<int> moreInts = new List<int>();
   moreInts.Add(10);
   ```
4. Generic list of ref type

   ```
   List<Person> morePeople = new List<Person>();
   morePeople.Add(new Person ("Frank", "Black", 50));
   ```

Comment: *1 = nongeneric list* No, it's an array of a reference type. *2 = nongeneric list of ref type* No, it's an array of a reference type (assuming `Person` is a `class`, not a `struct`).

Comment: Have a read of [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

1. String is not a value type
2. Array is not a value type
3. List is not a value type (and uses Array internally)

Both can be stored on the stack or the heap theoretically (or something entirely different!), that's not part of the specification. In practice, the stack is only used for in-scope things, and to simplify making sure that the references are in scope, it usually only puts value types on the stack, since those are easy to verify. However, they can also be stored in registers. It's up to the JIT compiler to decide that.

In unsafe code, you can explicitly allocate some pointers on the stack, but that's only in the unsafe code. Other than that, it's up to the implementation of the JIT compiler. However, with the current versions, you can be pretty certain that all that can't be verified to have life time limited enough, will be placed on the heap. The key thing here is *scope*, not whether it's a reference type or a value type. It's just that value types are generally easy to verify :)

If you have to think whether it's on the heap or the stack, it's probably on the heap. In any case, the point is "you don't care". Only care if you have performance profiling data to back up the fact that you do indeed have an issue related to this.

Remember - stack, heap, registers... all just an implementation detail in the managed memory model of .NET.

Answer (score -1):

Everebody. All arrays stored in heap.
If array type is struct, then values stored in cells of array.
List safe values in array.

For example:

1. strArray has 3 cells with 3 pointers to strings in heap
2. personArray has 1 cell with 1 pointer to Person class in heap
3. moreInts has 1 cell with 1 integer value in cell
4. morePeople has 1 cell with pointer to Person class in heap